# strange load 'something' caching in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

I am working with many classes in my controller. I have put them in different files. Since i still have not found the correct way to include them (to get my changes without restarting rails server), I use this on top of my controlers rb file: (this suggeston I found here on stack)

```
if Rails.env.development?
    load 'classes.rb'
else
    require 'classes'
end 

class FunController < ApplicationController
...
```

This wokrs fine, altough i still am searching for the correct solution.

**but(!)**

I put (not that trivial) code in classes.rb

```
class FunClass
 def initialize
  sayHello
  sayHello
 end

 def sayHello
  puts "hello"
 end
end
```

and - for sure! - I got my two Hellos

But I dont like "hello" i use "Hi", I had to change it, and made an error: 
code looks now:

```
class FunClass
 def initialize
  sayHi
  sayHello # <-- this one I have overseen
 end

 def sayHi
  puts "Hi"
 end
end
```

If you like riddles, guess what i got!

no, not an error

I got one 'Hi' and one 'Hello'

Although I am new to ruby-on-rails, I have a good idea what happens here, but isnt this more a bug than a feature?
restart Rails server and you get the expected error.

irl I accitently put a 's' (ctrl-s without ctrl) in the middle of a function name, and searched for hours why changes in this function did not pop up.

Am i totally wrong or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `require` or `load`: this will break rails' code reloading system. As long as FunClass is in fun_class.rb (in general the file name should be the underscore version of the class name) somewhere on rails autoload path, it will be loaded automatically when referenced, and reloaded between requests. By default lib isn't reloaded between requests.

The example you give is because when you call `load` the second time this reopens the existing class. While this allows methods to be redefined or added, it won't remove any methods not in the newer version of the file. This is how `load` works in ruby - not a rails thing.

Comment: I see, and what about class named FirstTry? first_try.rb? firstry_class, or shall i name the class 'FirstTryClass'? I cant find that in rails doc, sry. you have a link or a doc suggestion for me?

Comment: FirstTry should be in first_try.rb. FirstTryClass would be an odd name for a class but rails would look for it in first_try_class.rb

Comment: Ok, I am a noob on rails, ho do i tell ruby/rails to use the class without using include/load/require? Just a xxxx.new does not work.

Comment: Then either it's not in a file following that naming convention or the file isn't in the right place (where is it?)

Comment: done now, I was stuck in nessesary naming conventions and(!) reload algorithm of rails, i think i figured it now. That the Framework Rails, enforces/prohibits usage of the ruby language is hard for me to accept, like in every Framework, but i have to